# Mongoose result item count

Tags: mongoose, count

I How can I get the array count in a result of find e.g.

```
Person.find({'exployment.office':'Greenway'})
        .exec(function(err, result){
            //number of items in result
        });

        //how can I get the array of result which is number of items in the result.
```

Comment: Do you mean `result.length`?

Comment: that was what I was looking for. thanks